# Express $\partial f/\partial x$ and $\partial f/\partial y$ in terms of $\partial f/\partial r$ and $\partial f/\partial \theta$, and vice versa.

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, polar-coordinates, chain-rule

I wrote down the following: 
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} =  \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \cos(\theta) \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (1)
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} =  - \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \frac{\sin(\theta)}{r} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (2)
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \frac{\partial r}{\partial y} =  \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \sin(\theta) \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (3)
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y} =  \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \frac{\cos(\theta)}{r} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (4)
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} =  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \left [-r\sin(\theta) \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial r} + \cos(\theta) \right ] \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (5)
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} =  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \left [ -r \sin(\theta) + \cos(\theta) \frac{\partial r}{\partial \theta}\right ] \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (6)
\end{align}

It is possible to write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ purely in terms of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}$? And same for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$

Also, I think $\partial \theta / \partial r = \partial r / \partial \theta = 0$ so $(5)$ and $(6)$ become: 
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} =  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \left [ \cos(\theta) \right ] \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (5')
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} =  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \left [ -r \sin(\theta) \right ] \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (6')
\end{align}

Comparing $(5')$ with $(1)$ and comparing $(6')$ with $(2)$ is really confusing to me. Can anyone explain what am I doing incorrect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I resubstitute polar coordinates after differentiation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2708739/can-i-resubstitute-polar-coordinates-after-differentiation). It goes in the opposite direction, and uses $\varphi$ in place of $\theta$, but it's not too difficult to reverse the process.

Comment: In equation (1), it should be $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}.$$
And in equation (3), it should be $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}.$$
if 
$$
\begin{aligned}
x &= r\cos{\theta} \\
y &= r\sin{\theta},
\end{aligned}
$$
Then,
$$
\begin{aligned}
r &= \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \\
\theta &= \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right).
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that function $f(x, y)$ depends also on $(r, \theta)$ through

$$
\begin{aligned}
x &= x(r, \theta) \\
y &= y(r, \theta) \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Then,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}
\end{aligned}
$$

which can be rewritten in a matrix form:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} \\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

from which,

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} \\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Thus, if 
$$
\begin{aligned}
x(r, \theta) &= r\cos{\theta} \\
y(r, \theta) &= r\sin{\theta},
\end{aligned}
$$

then

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 \cos{\theta} & \sin{\theta} \\
-r\sin{\theta} & r\cos{\theta}
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
 \cos{\theta} & -\frac{\sin{\theta}}{r} \\
 \sin{\theta} & \frac{\cos{\theta}}{r}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos{\theta}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}-\frac{\sin{\theta}}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \\
\sin{\theta}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}+\frac{\cos{\theta}}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}
\end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow \\ \\
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= \cos{\theta}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}-\frac{\sin{\theta}}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} &= \sin{\theta}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}+\frac{\cos{\theta}}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}
\end{aligned}
$$